# Android TV Custom Presenter Error: Do not setLayoutFrozen in layout or scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, television, leanback

I had tried to create a custom presenter with just a single custom view whitch play a video into a surface view and after first bind i get this error message. What's the problem? I don't set any boolean to froze layour or any like this.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Do not setLayoutFrozen in layout or scroll
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2164)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(RecyclerView.java:1750)
at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BaseRowFragment.onTransitionStart(BaseRowFragment.java:199)
at android.support.v17.leanback.app.RowsFragment.onExpandTransitionStart(RowsFragment.java:483)
at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment.startHeadersTransitionInternal(BrowseFragment.java:435)
at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment.access$200(BrowseFragment.java:77)
at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment$3.onRequestChildFocus(BrowseFragment.java:546)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.BrowseFrameLayout.requestChildFocus(BrowseFrameLayout.java:124)
at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:740)
at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:740)
at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:740)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.requestChildFocus(RecyclerView.java:2081)
at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:740)
at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:740)
at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:740)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.requestChildFocus(RecyclerView.java:2081)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4341)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:591)
at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:6708)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6666)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6654)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager$2.cre    ateItem(GridLayoutManager.java:1473)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.SingleRow.appendVisibleItems(SingleRow.java:111)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Grid.appendOneColumnVisibleItems(Grid.java:364)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.appendOneColumnVisibleItems(GridLayoutManager.java:1696)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:1881)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.disp    atchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3026)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.disp    atchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2903)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3277)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecor    ated(RecyclerView.java:7629)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChild(GridLayoutManager.java:1631)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.access$2700(GridLayoutManager.java:53)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager$2.addItem(GridLayoutManager.java:1540)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.SingleRow.appendVisibleItems(SingleRow.java:124)
at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Grid.appendOneCol`
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for this? I have exactly the same crashes but I can not reproduce it

Comment: @MykhailoYuzheka no, i stopped working for Android TV for the moment. I will try when i buy a TV with Android.

Comment: Still facing this issue?

Comment: How to resolve this, i am facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

Presenter implementation looks okay. It seems like you're running a scroll or layout during entrance transition.

Did you subclass BrowseFragment properly? Can you share your app code.

Comment: I need to look the app code - specifically BrowseFragment/RowsFragment implementation to figure out the issue.